# Prevent popups, etc. from the new Google Image Search?

Tags: google-image-search

Short of disabling JavaScript, is there any way to stop the irritating behaviour of the new-fangled Google image search? I'm tired of having things pop up and down, move around, and scroll up and down wildly, not to mention these exasperating popup images.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few options here based on different browsers.  It is basically disabling JavaScript for Google Images ONLY - so it reverts to the old version.

It is strange how this isn't a preference on your Google account.

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/01/getting-old-google-image-search-back.html

This page also links to a GreaseMonkey script which does the job too.

The JavaScript route isn't great but this seems to be the best way to do it.  Especially as it only switches JavaScript off for Google Images.

There is also a URL hack.  Append the following to the end of the URL and it will display using the old version

`&sout=1`

Answer (score 3):

Add &sout=1 to the end of your search URL - it will give you the results in the old image search format.